# Manually convert TyphoonConfig

Tags: ios, swift, typhoon

Basically i want to do something like this.

```
public dynamic func someClass() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(SomeClass.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.useInitializer("initWithHost:") {
            (initializer) in

            let url: NSURL! = TyphoonConfig("someUrl") as NSURL
            initializer.injectParameterWith(url.host)
        }
    }
}
```

But TyphoonConfig() is from Type TyphoonInjectionByConfig.

Is it possible to convert the TyphoonConfig Object manually, or do i need to inject it and it will converted then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TyphoonConfig allows defining config in an external configuration file in either .properties, .plist or .json format. Since these formats provide limited types, Typhoon provides built-in type converters to transform the string representation to the required type. In-built converters exist for primitives and common types like NSURL, UIColor. You can also define your own.

To externalize an NSURL, create a definition referencing your config:

```
/*
 * A config definition, referencing properties that will be loaded from a plist. 
 */
public dynamic func config() -> AnyObject {

    return TyphoonDefinition.configDefinitionWithName("Configuration.plist")
}
```

Use it:

```
public dynamic func someClass() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(SomeClass.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.useInitializer("initWithHost:") {
            (initializer) in

            initializer.injectParameterWith(TyphoonConfig("someUrl"))
        }
    }
}
```

And create the config file as follows.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>someUrl</key>
    <string>NSURL(http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx)</string>
    <key>api.key</key>
    <string>dbaffee6eb10d4fdc1a5d333554e4</string>
    <key>days.to.retrieve</key>
    <string>NSNumber(5)</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note that we declare the value as `NSURL(http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx)`, meaning Typhoon will look in its registry of converters for one that can handle NSURL. You can also register your own converters, as described [here](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-configuration).

Comment: i forget the NSURL() in my plist. But if i try your example i get libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional: in this line     let url: NSURL! = TyphoonConfig("someUrl") as NSURL

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice it was written like that before. Change it to `initializer.injectParameterWith(TyphoonConfig("someUrl"))` . . . I will explain why in a separate question if you like.

Comment: So it will be converted inside of injectParameterWith?

Comment: That's right - this is a definition (or recipe) for assembling a built instance.

Comment: OK. One other note. plist and json formats allow nesting. Eg `<key>service</key><dict> <!-- dictionary here --> </dict>` and properties can be resolved as eg `service.host` or `service.logResponses` , etc.